# He prides himself on the longevity of the company. (meaning of the sentence)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He prides himself on the longevity of the company.

He worked for the company for a long time or the company survived for a long time?

Analysis — He prides himself (We know he is proud of himself), on the longevity (We know something has existed for a long time), of the company (1. 'of' as 'possessive' belonging to, 2. 'of' as 'about' which could imply his longevity, working for the company.)

his longevity or company's longevity?

Comment: How can one possibly confuse his longevity and the longevity of the company??

Comment: Two subjects exist simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Of" as possessive.

"longevity of the company" = "company's longevity"

"his longevity" would mean how long he has been alive, not how long he has worked at the company.

Comment: Is he the owner of the company? Why is he proud of himself?

Comment: Probably he is the owner, or he thinks that he is responsible for the longevity of the company in some way.

Comment: @Brandon - why should people not be proud of themselves?

Comment: @Michael - If it's his company, or has worked for a long time for the company, then he could pride himself on the longevity of the company. I could guess maybe he worked for a long time for the company(=his longevity) and that's why he prides himself on the company's longevity. Re-commenting induced me to this conclusion. It's amazing.